# change the format of a text file with apache pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have a txt file which has the following format:

```
{ (word1),(word2),(word3),....,(wordn) }
```

The words are NOT in quotes. I would like to use apache pig and change the format of this file simply to:

```
word1
word2
word3
wordn
```

Is there any way to do so with apache pig?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

**input**

```
{ (word1),(word2),(word3),(wordn) }
```

**PigScript1:**

```
A = LOAD 'input' AS (mybag:{T:(line:chararray)});
B = FOREACH A GENERATE REPLACE(BagToString(mybag.line),'_',' ');
STORE B INTO 'output';
```

**Output:(stored in output/part* file)**

```
word1 word2 word3 wordn
```

**Update:**(Incase if you want all the columns in a single row then use Flatten operator)
**PigScript2:**

```
A = LOAD 'input' AS (mybag:{T:(line:chararray)});
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(mybag);
STORE B INTO 'output1';
```

**Output:**

```
word1
word2
word3
wordn
```